# Inserting month in watermark is not using system locale

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, locale

I need to insert the date in the video with the format %d %b %Y. My locale configuration is in spanish:

```
❯ locale
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=es_ES.UTF-8
```

And if I run date I have the date in spanish format:

```
❯ date
mié 19 abr 2023 09:10:02 CEST
```

But when I insert a watermark with the date with the next command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text='%{localtime\:%d %B %Y}':x=10:y=10:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white@0.8" -codec:a copy video_with_watermark.mp4
```

I get a watermark in english:

```
19 April 2023
```

How can I force ffmpeg to use the locale of the system or how can I pass a parameter to specify the locale in the command?

Comment: there was some workaround, if you interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74609009/how-do-i-make-ffmpeg-use-localized-strftime-with-drawtext/74624234